# Scaling Mariadb Galera Cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have installed MariaDB Galera Cluster on ubuntu 14 and it is working fine.

[See the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-ubuntu-12-04-servers)

I have 3 nodes (each 500GB HDD capacity) mariadb cluster and all replications are working perfect.

**My questions are :**

*When I run out of disk space after few years, What is the exact way to increase the capacity of the database?*

*Is it possible to add extra nodes and increase the database HDD capacity?* I heard about MaxScale, but I can't figure it out to work on

Can anyone explain this according to above configuration.

[This is a MaxScale Simple Sharding with Two Servers](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale/maxscale-simple-sharding-with-two-servers/)

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

The nodes in a Galera cluster could have different hard disk capacity (as general rule the nodes can be different from each other).
When you need to increase disk capacity you can put offline a node, upgrade the disk and then restart it.
When the node with new disk is joined and synced with the cluster, you can upgrade another node and go on.